# Finding the smallest angle between two vectors

Tags: vectors

I have two vectors: 
$A = i-3j+2k$ and
$B = -3i+4j-k.$

I have already found the angle between the two  to be ~$157.6$ degrees, but I am required to find the smallest angle between the two - I am not sure what that means exactly and can't seem to find the answer online. I would be glad if you could help me out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are position vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Two vectors describe a plane so I presume you are being asked to find the angle between the two vectors in the plane they describe.

I've added a small illustration (done in Geogebra) to show what I mean. The two points $A$ and $B$ are described by the vectors you gave. The blue plane is described by $A, B$ and the origin and the angle between these two vectors is $153^{\circ}$ (not sure if the angle is properly visible). You can compute this angle via the dot product. If you used the dot product and got to $157.6^{\circ}$ there may be a rounding error of some description in your calculation. Either way, I believe this may be what your teacher is looking for. Does this help?

[image: Plane]

Comment: This would be more appropriate in the comments section.

Comment: I agree! My lack of reputation means that I am not yet allowed to comment everywhere.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not remember that rule applies. For what it's worth, it's a usefull hint!

Comment: Thanks, I hope it helps the asker. Only 6 more reputation to go before I am deemed trustworthy enough to contribute to the community in the form of comments! Haha

Comment: I don't have any kind of sketch in that problem, so I am not exactly sure how to relate a plane to this - I am new to the topic of vectors, so perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Do you know what the answer is? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It's from my teacher's presentation. The answer is not indicated, sadly.

Comment: I have re-calculated it and I arrive at exactly 153∘ as well. Thank you. And yes, the angle is very much visible in fact.

Comment: Wonderful! If this helped, feel free to upvote (so I'll finally be able to comment on future posts!)

Comment: I tried to upvote, however, it notes that I can only do that once I have 15rep. So, I could only sadly mark it as solved :)
Unless it adds a point for you, even if not displayed here.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your future studies.